# How to delete traces from plotly chart with checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, checkbox, plotly

I have multiple checkboxes to plot data in to my plotly chart.
I want to delete traces from chart when unchecked.

```
 <input id="4" type="checkbox" value="radio" onclick="getTraces(this)"/>
 <input id="5" type="checkbox" value="micro" onclick="getTraces(this)"/>
```

getTraces() calls Plotly.addTraces and pass data from Database

```
 Plotly.addTraces[x:[],y:[]] // add traces in to chart
```

delete Traces is possible with

```
 Plotly.deleteTraces[]// pass the position of the trace to delete trace.
```

My Problem is i need to pass the position of the trace i want to delete.
How can i safe the position of the traces? 
What i thought is to safe somehow the sequence of my checked checkboxes.
If i would know that checkbox one was checked first, 
then the position of the graph would be also first.

always when i call

```
Plotly.addTraces[x:[],y:[]]
```

there is a new element in the data Array of the Plot.
like this : data[trace1,trace2,trace3].

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution for my answer.

```
    Plotly.addTraces[x:[],y:[],name:"Chart1"] // add traces in to chart
```

i get the chart by

```
  chart3 = document.getElementById('chart3');  
  for(var i=0;i<chart3.data.length;i++)
  {
      if(chart3.data[i]["name"]==nameofCharttodelete)
      {
           Plotly.deleteTraces('chart3',i);     
      }
  }
```

i loop through the data array of the chart and compare the name from the chart with my checkbox value.